# How Can I Quickly Restore a Cluster When a Power Failure Occurs?

Tags: ignite

The ignite I use is embedded.
When I stop one service, ignite can quickly restore the cluster by sending a TcpDiscoveryNodeLeftMessage message to other nodes through the ShutdownHook mechanism.
However, when one service is powered off, other services cannot quickly recover the cluster.

How Can I Quickly Restore a Cluster When a Power Failure Occurs?

Comment: Hi what are the services you're talking about? Are they Ignite Services? And what do you mean by "recover"?

Comment: Ignite is released and deployed with my microservice in JAR format，not Ignite Services。Other services cannot quickly re-establish a cluster. For example, if five nodes form a cluster, one node is powered off, and the other four nodes cannot quickly re-establish a new cluster.

Comment: Is there any logs on other nodes after failure? Is Ignite Persistence enabled?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.